# how to recover win7 licence to update to win10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, license-key, serial-number

I have a DELL laptop pc, coming from a company (free) so no DVD or paperwork available, just the hardware. I have a perfect legit win7 pro 32 bit version running on it just fine. I whant to keep this pc, so i made the windows update, download it and install all 208 update. Restart -> blue screen of death... NOTHING can be done to recover from this... a HD driver problem.

So what i have done, take the HD out, copy everything from the HD to a server just in case, format the HD and install win10 64 bit from DVD

SO the question is, how can i recover the legit serial from windows 7 (i still have the files) and get a legal version of win10 running

Comment: Your Windows 7 device has a COA sticker with your product key on it..

Answer (score -1):

If it's a Dell laptop, there should be a sticker on the bottom containing the windows license and serial number.  If that's missing or too worn away, you can download something like http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html and run it on the files you saved from the old Win7 installation.

Answer (score -1):

Did you image the drive? If you created an ISO image, you can mount it, boot from it, and retrieve the key from the registry. Here's an example of how you can do that:

http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/